# Why do Muslims say "As-salamu 'alaykum" (plural -kum), even when only one person is addressed?

Tags: arabic, adab

Shouldn't it vary depending on the number and the gender of the addressee, e.g. 'alayka, 'alayki, 'alaykuma ? But I almost never heard the other variation. Is there a religious or grammatical reason for this, or is it just non-Arab Muslims unfamiliar with Arabic grammar?

Comment: Maybe also helpful http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/5796/what-does-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%83%D9%85-%D8%A3%D9%8A%D9%87%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D8%A8%D9%8A-actually-mean

Answer (score 3):

I think that it is the lack of knowledge of the people who do not speak the Arabic language and for those who speak it naturally, lack of education.

When addressing 1 person male, it should be said:

> Alsalam Alika
>
> السلام عليكَ

While addressing a 1 person female, it should be said:

> Asalam Aliki
>
> السلام عليكِ

For example, take the [following Hadith](http://sunnah.com/adab/42/71)

> قَالَ أَبُو عَبْدِ اللهِ‏‏ وَقَالَتْ قَيْلَةُ‏‏ قَالَ رَجُلٌ‏‏ السَّلاَمُ عَلَيْكَ يَا رَسُولَ اللهِ، قَالَ‏‏ وَعَلَيْكَ السَّلاَمُ وَرَحْمَةُ اللهِ‏
>
> Qayla reported that a mans aid, "Peace be upon you, may Allah bless him and grant him peace." He said, "And peace be upon you and the mercy of Allah."

The same is true when viewing many [other hadiths](http://sunnah.com/search/?q=%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%20%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%83) of the same nature. It was never reported from the Sunnah or general Arabic culture about 1 person meeting another 1 person and giving him/her the salutation for the many, just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I don't know why your comment was down voted considering you provided direct reference to back up your point.

Comment: This is not the reason. Rather some scholars hold that it is recommended to use the plural even for a single person, as we should include  in the greeting the angels who accompany the person. See [Al-Adab Al-Mufrad 1037](https://sunnah.com/adab:1037) and also [Sharah Nawawi](https://shamela.ws/book/1711/3174):  والأفضل أن يقول السلام عليكم ليتناوله وملكيه

Comment: Also they rely on the apparent meaning of the hadith recorded by [Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:2721) ‏ إذا لقي الرجل أخاه المسلم فليقل السلام عليكم ورحمة الله (When a man meets his Muslim brother then he should say: "As-Salamu 'Alaikum Wa Rahmatullahi Wa Barakatuh")

Answer (score 1):

WHY DO MUSLIMS GREET IN PLURAL

As-salāmu ʿalaykum written in Arabic as السَّلَامُ عَلَيْكُمْ‎ is the standard Muslim greeting which means "peace be upon you all" in plural and for all genders even when addressing one person. When I was growing up I heard our elders spoke about the two kiraman katibin كراماً كاتبين‎ which means the "two honourable scribes" who are two unseen angels called Raqib and Atid who sit the right and left shoulders of everyone with the duty to record our good and bad deeds. The Quran refers to them in two places, in 50:16-18 and by name as 'Noble Recorders' in 82:10-12. My understanding is that when we greet one person in plural we are actually greeting that person’s assigned scribes as well – hence we say “peace be upon you all”.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and model I strongly suggest you to take the [tour] and check our [help].

Answer (score 0):

In the Arabic language you show respect to the person by using a plural instead of a singular. This is why in the Quran Allah is often addresses as We, even though there is only one god

Answer (score -1):

It's in plural because the greeting is directwd to the person and the two angels guarding each one of us, according to the Islamic culture. Me, as an Arabic student and translator, I feel deply embarassed to see that someone decided to judge all Arabic speakers and Muslims as poorly educated without trying to search a bit deeper in the cultural or religious explanation.
There are indeed hadith in the sunna regarding the use of the plural and even discouraging the singular, as it is considered the greeting given to the dead.

Answer (score -1):

It can be relevant for being angel(s) who are always with the human in order to noting good and bad deeds of us. (Therefore we use that with the intention of greeting or saying hello to our parties and the angels as well)

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please conisder to take your time to learn more about ou site and model by taking our 2 min. [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score -2):

Muslims say Assalam o Alaikom (al salamo alaikum) even to someone (single) as well as the case or the form of plural?

This can have some reasons for saying Assalamo alaikom (in plural shape) instead of assalamo alaik (which is for the single for of that.

It can be possible to be relevant to some countries cultures.

It can be used as a habit that some or many people use it like that.

It can be relevant for being angel(s) who are always with the human in order to noting good and bad deeds of us. (Therefore we use that with the intention of greeting or saying hello to our parties and the angels as well)

And eventually it is used in order to showing our respect (more respect) to the individuals who we are saying hello to