# Thinking of Prophet Muhammad Sallallaho Alaihi Wasallam during Namaz

Tags: salat, prophet-muhammad, sunni, darood

I am a **Sunni** Muslim. Though, we all read darood in Namaz and know that darood-e-ibrahim which we read has **Mahammad (Sallallo Alaihi Wasallam)'s** name many times. I think of my beloved Prophet every time I read darood. So how can Wahabi's scholars say that one cannot think of Prophet during Namaz.

Comment: I never heard this before. So could you please provide a source for the statement about Wahabi scholars?

Comment: Ismaeel Dahelvi, a Wahabi scholar wrote in his book Sirate Mustaqeem.

Comment: Is your objection to thinking about the Prophet (PBUH) during the **whole prayer**, or just while reciting the **Tashahud**?

Comment: I said during Namaz, it can be anytime.

Comment: @ZAS, do you think that thinking of the Prophet (PBUH) is considered part of your Khusho' (concentration) in your prayer? How about pondering on the verses that you recite in your prayer?

Comment: @Atata: Do you think that thinking of Prophet Muhammad Sallallaho Alaihi Wasallam is not good? And your answer is Yes and we do think deeply about the verses we know, no doubt about it.

Comment: @ZAS, I never claimed that! Plus, you clearly stated in your question " I think of my beloved Prophet every time I read **darood**", and that's different than thinking of him during the **whole prayer**

Comment: @Atata: So, isn't it during Namaz or after reciting darood I may think. I wrote about me, one can think prior to reciting too, it depends right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36650/discussion-between-zas-and-atata).

Comment: See also: "[What does “السلام عليكم أيها النبي” actually mean?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/5796/9123)"